# The best way to perform an Inner join with multiple tables (12) with Symfony Doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, inner-join, symfony

I'm building an api with FosrestBundle using Symfony and Doctrine. And I want to create a resource with get that will output json datas from the result of "inner joins" with more than 12 tables. To perform that, I want to create a query in the repository with doctrine sql and then retrieve it in my controller.
Is it a good way to go or there's better ?

Comment: Quick thought: Creating a view/procedure/... in SQL and working with that in your PHP might be a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

Basically there's no problem with that, though 12 tables does sound a bit large. Perhaps think about if there's a more efficient way to group the data.

And if it's the same data that you are sending over and over again (e.g. you are sending a public blog post content via an API), be sure to include a caching system so as to not join the tables over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

If your tables are not too large, this might be okay. If you're encountering performance issues, try using plain SQL to achieve a speedy result. Doctrine is hydrating every join, so that may slow you down.

You could use this one instead:

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("[YOUR SQL]");
$stmt->bindValue(':value', $value);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also user `createQueryBuilder()`. Here is small example.

Assuming you have tables such as `tbl_1`, `tbl_2`, `tbl_3`, `tbl_4`, `tbl_5`.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('tbl_1')
    ->select('tbl_1')
    ->innerJoin('tbl_1.tbl2_records', 'tbl_2')
    ->innerJoin('tbl_1.tbl3_records', 'tbl_3')
    ->innerJoin('tbl_1.tbl4_records', 'tbl_4')
    ->innerJoin('tbl_2.tbl5_records', 'tbl_5')
    ->OrderBy('tbl_1.amount', 'ASC');
```

[Link](http://anjanasilva.com/blog/sql-into-dql-examples-symfony-2-doctrine-2/) can help you out.